# Programatic scheduled Report Generation & store it in a external system

Tags: analytics

We have a request to be able to :
a. Provide an Interface where a User can select a Salesforce Report Name
b. Define its Schedule information (Weekly, Monthly)
c. Number of Days to Retain the file on the external system

How we can read the above information through a Batch Job and generate the report and then store it on a external application.

As we cannot access the standard report schedule using APEX we can build a custom VF page, where we can show the list of reports available and give them a custom interface to schedule the report; these report schedule details can be stored in a custom object. (I believe we can query the Reports object or we could use the below URL to get all the reports list:https://myinstance.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ReportList)

Then we can write a daily APEX batch job to parse through this custom object and fetch the reports (no charts, primarily tabular or sumary reports) that needs to be executed on a given day.

Then we can generate the below Report url, which needs to be exported and stored in the external system.

https://myinstance.salesforce.com/?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv,

1. but how can this be done using APEX or should we use Analytics API to run the report and save the results in excel or csv format.
2. What would be the best way to send the generated report to an external application

Can anyone suggest what are the possible approach/design/solutions for this request (Without considering any app exchange apps - Conga courier)

Comment: have you looked at the [apex report namespace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_namespace_Reports.htm)? it gives you programmatic ability to run a report and retrieve a structured representation of it's output (it's not an export, so you'd need to generate some sort of text output for storage in the external system)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the comments. I am able to export the data from salesforce report into csv using namespace (within apex); also i was able to make a http post request of multipart/form-data. However is there any way to export the data from Salesforce report directly in APEX into PDF format instead of csv (without using VF  page render as option).

Comment: no, but it seems like you've got two good options, conga courier, and vf to pdf functionality, why re-invent the wheel?